# Neo4j - cypher query performance optimization

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization, graph-databases

I have the following Neo4j Cypher query.
What this intend to do is, it checks for the cases where there is no incoming edges to a node and deletes the outgoing edges. This will execute on a loop until the return count is 0.
This query works as expected for a smaller data set but takes a lot of time and it hangs when running for a bigger dataset.

I would appreciate any help in optimizing this query.

`match (n1)-[e1]->(n2)-[:infer_using_std_err]->(n3) where not (n1)-[:infer_using_std_err]->(n2) 
match (n4)-[:infer_using_std_err]->(n5) 
with collect(distinct(n5)) as node_lst1, collect(distinct(n2)) as node_lst2 
with filter(k IN node_lst2 WHERE NOT k IN node_lst1) as res_node_lst unwind res_node_lst as r1 
match(r1)-[e:infer_using_std_err]->(r2) 
delete(e) 
return count(e)`